# How to automatically redirect to refresh token endpoint, and then redirect to previously called endpoint?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, razor-pages, refresh-token

Im using ASP.NET
I have two different application:

1. WEB API server on .NET Core
2. Client on .NET MVC with RazorPages
   I have authorization with JWT + RefreshToken
   I want to implement next thing:
   If I call some endppoint with expired token, it should automaticaly redirect to the refrehToken endpoint and call previous called endpoint

I tried to think how to implement this. I found some stuff about interceptor but I didnt find it for RazorPages(only for Blazor)